# Should questions be edited down to their base question?

Tags: discussion

An edit came up for a question I asked a while ago ( https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3872270/revisions )

The original question was:

> I stored (or think I stored) some text from a textbox that is effectively 'lol\ncats'
>
> In SQL management studio it comes up in the description has 'lol cats'
>
> How can I check if the \n is there or not?

It was edited to:

> I have a varchar column that contains the string `lol\ncats`, however, in SQL Management Studio it shows up as `lol cats`.
>
> How can I check if the `\n` is there or not?

In this case it has actually lost the original problem in the edit, so I would modify it to say I have a column that may or may not contain a newline character (because checking if \n appears in a string that has \n in is pointless as you know it already exists!). Also the introduction of `varchar` is incorrect and makes the problem more specific so I would probably remove that.

However apart from that, is this sort of edit (condensing and trimming a question down) a good thing, and is it something I should be striving to do as well?

Comment: Well, the questions should be edited to remove localized stuff that doesn't belong to the problem, so that question is easier to find and can be used by more people with a similar issue. The sad thing is, no one actually takes the time to do that. The only important thing (that I can currently think of) is that your problem is still reproducable with the remaining information. So if you think `varchar` is incorrect here, then fix that.

Comment: I can't help but wonder why you only came to this realisation after having asked more than 500 questions?

Comment: I don't mean writing concise questions so much as if I see a question that is understandable if it should be further trimmed down to be as concise as possible.

Answer (score 4):

> is this sort of edit (condensing and trimming a question down) a good thing, and is it something I should be striving to do as well?

You don't post questions to Stack Overflow for just yourself, you post them so others that have the same problem can find it and its answers.

When someone else reads your question, they're going to want to evaluate whether the problem described actually applies to the problem they're having.

So **yes**, trim down a question to its most minimal form and make sure you add all relevant information.

This is also explained on the pages [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: *Explain how you encountered the problem you're trying to solve, and any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself. The first paragraph in your question is the second thing most readers will see, so make it as engaging and informative as possible.* I put from a Textbox which is I guess, irrelevant, but it is how I encountered the problem. I guess I'm asking if questions should edited to be sterilised of background and personality and to what extent. Minimal & Verifiable guidelines are about ensuring you have the minimum, not ensuring you have *only* the minimum, it seems.

Comment: Yes, the "from a textbox" part is entirely relevant. What is relevant is that you have a string variable containing a newline. It doesn't matter where this variable came from; could be a file, an input control, a webservice or hardcoded. Neither changes anything about the problem: a newline is a newline. In my opinion you should remove _anything_ that's considered "background" and "personality", as long as those aspects don't change anything about the question.